Alternative way for putting a huge dataset inside IN() clause to increase the performance?
Please take a look at the following query:
SELECT cc.number_card
  FROM customers_cards cc
  JOIN customers_card_psp ccp
    ON cc.id = ccp.card_id
   AND ccp.psp_id = '12'
   AND ccp.status = 'old_ofogh_koorosh'
 WHERE cc.number_card IN ('5892101311148569',
                          '6104338967224862',
                          '5894631571684950', 
                          '5894631565301181',
                          '5894631115309510',
                          ...
                          ...
                          );

I dynamically put ~5k number_card inside that IN(...) clause using a PHP-loop and then execute the query.
The problem is, it scans the same as number_card numbers and it's a bit non-optimal. See the EXPLAIN:

Any idea how can I rewrite the query to be more optimal?

But it uses an index already... which is much better than using LIKE with wildcards. What is the actual problem?

@HonkderHase The problem is that 5k (hard-codded) card numbers  sometimes get increased to over 20k, and in that case the performance drops sharply.

Perhaps the same performance, but have you tried putting the numbers in a CTE or TMP table and joining to it?

Is CTE or TMP a real table? I mean creating it with CREATE TABLE <tbname> ...? I cannot do that since that list is dynamic and changes every time

TMP table does use create statement, but only valid for that session. CTE does not use create statement, but might be ugly.

Hmm. When performance drops (with 20k), which type is chosen in EXPLAIN? Does the DB falls back to an FTS? Could explain the drop in performance... can you trigger this situation?

Can you post the execution plan in json format when you have the list with 20k ? Run EXPLAIN FORMAT = JSON your_query...

Dump into an indexed temp table, then do a join. That is the only performant method. Giant IN lists are always slow. In other DBMSs such as SQL Server you can use a Table Valued Parameter.

Numbers in EXPLAIN are estimates; do not trust the "5541".  What datatype is number_card?

As some of the comments suggested, a good solution might be to create a bona fide table to contain the 5K number_card values.  Then, index that new table on the number_card value to allow for rapid lookup.  However, given that the 5K values change for each query, this approach won't work.
Instead, we can focus on tuning the rest of the query and leaving your approach as is.  Consider adding the following indices:
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON customers_cards (id, number_card);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON customers_card_psp (card_id, psp_id, status);

Which of these two indices would be used depends on the query plan MySQL decides to use, but either should speed up the overall query as you have written it.
