Why using index caused more rows scanning?
Please take a look at the following query:
SELECT cc.number_card
FROM customers_cards cc
   JOIN customers_card_psp ccp
      ON cc.id = ccp.card_id 
        AND ccp.psp_id = '12' 
        AND ccp.status = 'old_ofogh_koorosh'
   JOIN xxx
      ON xxx.card_number = cc.number_card

Note, xxx is a temp table:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx ( 
   card_number varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
)


Here is the result of EXPLAIN when there is no index for xxx table:

And here is the result of EXPLAIN when there is a index xxx(card_number):


As you can see, in the no-index situation, less rows get scanned. So, what's preferred? Using an index or not?

Is the larger number the number of rows in the temp table?

The temp table has 6002 rows for both cases @Barmar

The rows field of EXPLAIN is only a rough estimate, not a precise count. It can vary by +/- 50% in my experience, and can change each time you run EXPLAIN for the same query against the same tables.

Oh, really @BillKarwin?! I thought it's an accurate number.

@BillKarwin It can vary by +/- 50% in my experience I've seen a difference of 10 times...

I'd make card_number the primary key, just to keep innodb from having to make up an invisible primary key.  but re row numbers, first just see which is faster.

note that this is a followon question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78391269/alternative-way-for-putting-a-huge-dataset-inside-in-clause-to-increase-the-pe

If you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html: "The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query. For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact." The manual is making an understatement. In my experience the rows is always inexact, and can be way, way off. But that's adequate for the purpose of guiding the optimizer for which index to use, and ensuring that it's precise would be very costly for MySQL.

If you are building and dropping that temp table every time you run the main query, does having the temp really save over using IN()?

Or joining a values table constructor
